# Timeshift 18.9.1 - Cant add Comments to btrfs snapshots

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, backup, btrfs, snapshot

I often use timeshift snapshots with btrfs (and also snapper on servers).
Bot have a comments field for each snapshot.

With snapper, i can add a comment as a command-line option.
Timeshift also adds comments to snapshots f.e. "before rollback of snapshot xy", but i dont find an option to add comments when i manually create a snapshot.

Is there a different snapshot menu im missing, or does timeshift not support user added comments ?

Answer (score 4):

OK, found out how to add comments, sadly, this feature is not well documented in the timeshift gui.
Too obvious to me, i was looking for a menu.

Comments can be added/edited by **clicking in the comments field**.

Its also possible to add commments in the console

console:

```
timeshift --create --comment "comment text here"
or with additionall tags   
timeshift --create --comment "comment text here" --tags O

--tags {O,B,H,D,W,M}
[W]eekly, [D]aily, [M]onthly, [B]oot, [O]ther (Manualy created)
```

show snapshots:
    timeshift --list

help can be accessed by typing "timeshift" without options